# GUI for LAN Shares

Tags: networking, file-sharing

Installed Rasbian on a Raspberry Pi, but cannot figure out how to transfer files over the network.

Shares are always a pretty hit and miss affair, but I cannot even figure out if the pi sees the PC or if it is just an access rights problem. And I simply do not want some terminal auto mount script, I want a window with the connected computers and their shares listed.

Comment: Have your tried a piece of software called FileZilla? I have used it and it works flawlessly, it shows both the file directories for the Pi and your PC at the same time. Allowing you to simply drag and drop items from one onto the other.

Comment: Do you mean setup a filezilla server on one box and then connect to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filezilla is the simplest way to do it.

You can install it on one Pi and use it to see the directories on both, for transferring.

It is easily installed:

```
sudo apt-get install filezilla
```

All it needs is the IP address - set it to use sftp, and to use a Normal Login, then put in the username and password.  When you clock on Connect it saves the entry for future use.  In the Advanced tab you can have it default to directories other than just the home directory ~

You need to have SSH enabled on both systems, of course.

That can be done through

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can install FileZilla on a Windows computer to access your Pi computers using only their IP address.  It is a one-size-fits-all solution to sharing files.  The other advantage is that the Pi doesn't even need to be publishing shares for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are trying to look for files using your Raspberry Pi.  These files are located on another computer.  Check out this [answer from the PiHut](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/19669700-using-network-storage-on-the-raspberry-pi).  It shows you how to connect to another server and then use the built-in File Manager to look at those machines' file structures.

Comment: Whilst the PiHut's solution may be correct it would be nice to see a summary of the information in your answer.

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.